# jQuery post returns empty response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm having a big problem over the last week and I can't seem to figure out a solution.

I'm trying to post some raw XML to a server that another company has developed for us that has, I think a listener to receive this XML input. I'm posting and sending the information just fine the thing is that I don't get any response back (just like every girl I liked in highschool...).

The error i get from Chrome is: >POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/SLISMESSAGE net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
and I've tried other browsers also but all of them the same deal except for Firefox that gives me a CORS error.

When I post the listener on the the server just says: Get Request /SLISMESSAGE.

```js
var template = [
            '<?xml version="1.0"?><request type="create-order"><PATIENT><CODE><?CODE?></CODE><DEPARTURE_DATE><?DEPARTURE_DATE?></DEPARTURE_DATE><LASTNAME><?LASTNAME?></LASTNAME><FIRSTNAME><?FIRSTNAME?></FIRSTNAME><BIRTHDAY><?BIRTHDAY?></BIRTHDAY><SEX><?SEX?></SEX><PHONE1><?PHONE1?></PHONE1><EMAIL><?EMAIL?></EMAIL><HOTEL><?HOTEL?></HOTEL><HOTELNO><?HOTELNO?></HOTELNO></PATIENT><ORDER><ORDERNO><?ORDERNO?></ORDERNO><ORDERDATE><?ORDERDATE?></ORDERDATE><ORDERTIME><?ORDERTIME?></ORDERTIME><SENDERCODE><?SENDERCODE?></SENDERCODE></ORDER><TESTS><TEST><?TEST?></TEST></TESTS></request>'
            ].join('\r\n');

            function update() {
                var len = 10;
                var randomId = parseInt((Math.random() * 9 + 1) * Math.pow(10,len-1), 10);
                //console.log(randomId.toString());
                
                var variables = {
                    'CODE': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][25]"]').val(),//randomId.toString(),
                    'DEPARTURE_DATE':$('input[name="wpforms[fields][3][date]"]').val(),
                    'DEPARTURE_TIME':$('input[name="wpforms[fields][3][time]"]').val(),
                    'LASTNAME': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][6][last]"]').val(),
                    'FIRSTNAME': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][6][first]"]').val(),
                    'BIRTHDAY': $('input[name="BIRTHDAY"]').val(),
                    'SEX': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][9]"]').val(),
                    'PHONE1': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][14]"]').val(),
                    'EMAIL': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][15]"]').val(),
                    'HOTEL': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][16]"]').val(),
                    'HOTELNO': $('input[name="wpforms[fields][17]"]').val(),
                    'TEST':$('input[name="wpforms[fields][2]"]').val(),
                    'ORDERNO':$('input[name="wpforms[fields][25]"]').val()
                };

                var newXml = template.replace(/<\?(\w+)\?>/g,
                    function(match, name) {
                        return variables[name];
                    });
                console.log(newXml);
                var parsedNewXml = $.parseXML(newXml);
                //console.log(parsedNewXml);
                
                var order_num = document.getElementById("wpforms-1034-field_25")

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8008/SLISMESSAGE", 
                    method: 'POST',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    timeout:0,
                    data: newXml,
                    contentType: "application/xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success : function(){
                        console.log('XML Sent');
                        alert("Data sent");
                    },
                    error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
                        console.log(xhr.status);          
                        console.log(thrownError);
                        console.log('HEYYYYYYYYYYYY');
                        alert(order_num);
                    } 
                });
```

The thing is when I try to post the same XML from postman I get a response. And the weirdest of them all, when I try to post with a python script I also get a response! ????????
Note that I'm not that good at JS or jQuery and there might be something I'm really missing here but if not then WTH?

I don't know what to do. At this point I'm almost at the point of giving up even though that would mess up a lot of things in the future but I have no idea what to do...

[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M14QF.jpg)

[Response Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLFYk.jpg)

[Results of Python Code and JS jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mghve.jpg)

**Python is in blue JS in red**

Note that I'm not that good at JS or jQuery and there might be something I'm really missing here but if not then WTH?

I don't know what to do. At this point I'm almost at the point of giving up even though that would mess up a lot of things in the future but I have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a CORS issue. You can see in the console tab in developer tools if you are getting cors error. Because browser blocks the response if cors is not properly configured. When you hit the api from Python the cors issue wont be happening because the cors check happens in the browser and not in Python